# first and second row need different margin

Tags: margins

My minimal code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}

\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,enumitem,setspace}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[
  poster = {
    columns=1,
    rows=2,
    spacing=3mm,
    height=14cm,
    width=12cm,
  },
]

\posterbox[colframe=red,width=4cm,height=4cm]{column=1}{
 %\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0]
1. This will break to two lines

2. This will break to two lines

3. This will break to two lines


}
\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

I need 2. line will move left.
Please help, Thanks
[image]

Comment: why you not use `itemize` for your list?

Comment: if 2.line of each item can move left, i want to use "itemize"

Comment: of course, just try and see.

Comment: BTW, I get different results using your code.  How did you get your image in the first place?

Comment: @JohnKormylo image that i want to display, not my code create this image

Comment: You can also achieve this effect with \parindent.  With columns this narrow, you might also consider \raggedright (before \parindent).

Comment: @JohnKormylo can you please add detail to code? i tried but fail. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple possibility with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}

\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem, setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbposter}[
  poster = {
    columns=1,
    rows=2,
    spacing=3mm,
    height=14cm,
    width=12cm,
  },
]

\posterbox[colframe=red,width=4cm,height=4cm]{column=1}{
 \begin{enumerate}[wide, leftmargin =-1em, rightmargin=-1em]
\item This will break to two lines, or even more.

\item This will break to two lines.

\item This will break to two lines.
\end{enumerate}
}
\end{tcbposter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to use `\parindent`.  One can also set it using `\setlength`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}

\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,enumitem,setspace}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[
  poster = {
    columns=1,
    rows=2,
    spacing=3mm,
    height=14cm,
    width=12cm,
  },
]

\posterbox[colframe=red,width=4cm,height=4cm]{column=1}{
 %\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0]
\raggedright
\parindent=1em
1. This will break to two lines

2. This will break to two lines

3. This will break to two lines


}
\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]